# Excel - Leave cell blank if no date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to have the day of week displayed in a cell only if there is a date present.

In the day of week (`H4`) cell I have `=TEXT(G4,"ddd")` which shows they day of week when the date is inputted into H4. However, when `G4` is blank it is showing "Sat" in `H4`.

How do I make it so nothing shows unless a date is entered into `G4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(G4),"",TEXT(G4,"ddd"))
```

`ISBLANK` will check if `G4` is blank. If it is, it will display empty text; otherwise, it will display the day of the week.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
=IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(G4)),"",TEXT(G4,"ddd"))
```

This will check if `G4` contains a number. This way it will display empty text if the cell is blank or contains text.